# Db connection problem on Azure Since database moved on CLEARDB

Tags: database

I built an wordpress blog on Azure, but since some time, the database is moved on CleadrDB (www.cleardb.com) By Azure certainly and then I don't have access to my site as admin : http://elbouachri-blogs.azurewebsites.net/wp-admin/

My userName on ClearDB is Username: da82f9e2bd69a0

I have this message :

```
Can’t select database

We were able to connect to the database server (which means your username and password is okay) but not able to select the db_100052017_blogging database.
•Are you sure it exists?
•Does the user bd0cc2e2bcc68c have permission to use the db_100052017_blogging database?
•On some systems the name of your database is prefixed with your username, so it would be like username_db_100052017_blogging. Could that be the problem?

If you don’t know how to set up a database you should contact your host. If all else fails you may find help at the WordPress Support Forums.
```

Any help please !

Comment: your password, or the DB address are incorrect. it is hard to be able to say more than that without actual access to your server

Comment: Thinks Mark ! I solved my problem by asking for help directly at CLEARDB. I sent them my identifiers and they did the necessary. As you have noticed it is a connection problem.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by asking for help directly at CLEARDB. I sent them my identifiers and they did the necessary. It is a connection problem.